# Component not updating on store change - Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, store, vuex

TLDR:

I recorded a video explaining my issue if that helps.
https://youtu.be/Qf9Q4zIaox8

**Navbar component is not updating on store change.**

I have separated my component into two sections using a v-if and v-else. When the user is logged in the v-if shows and when the user is't logged in, the v-else shows.

When I login, server authenticates, and the client commits a mutation to the store and sets the user and client token. When this is set, it sets a property in the state called "userIsLoggedIn" to true - This property is computed in the navbar component. For reasons unknown, the Navbar component does not update once the user is logged in ( despite the isLoggedIn property being true) UNLESS I refresh the page.

Navbar Component:

```js
<template>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <h1 class="navbar-item">
                    <router-link to="/" class="has-text-black">Logo</router-link>
                </h1>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-menu">
                <div class="navbar-end" v-if="isLoggedIn">
                    <div class="navbar-item">
                        <router-link to="/play" class="has-text-black">Play</router-link>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-item">
                        {{user.balance.toFixed(2)}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
                        <a class="navbar-link">
                            {{user.username}}
                        </a>

                        <div class="navbar-dropdown">
                            <div class="navbar-item">Profile</div>
                            <div class="navbar-item">Deposit</div>
                            <div class="navbar-item" @click="logout">Logout</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-item">
                        FAQ
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="navbar-end" v-else>
                    <div class="navbar-item">
                        <router-link to="/login" class="has-text-black">Login</router-link>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-item">
                        <router-link to="/register" class="has-text-black">Register</router-link>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-item">FAQ</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- container -->
    </div> <!-- navbar -->
</template>

<script>

import {mapGetters} from "vuex";
export default {
    name: "Navbar",
    data() {
        return {
            user: this.$store.state.user,
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
            "isLoggedIn",
        ])
    },

    methods: {
        logout() {
            this.$store.dispatch("setToken", null);
            this.$store.dispatch("setUser", null);
            this.$router.push({
                path: "/"
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Vuex Store:

```js
import Vue from "vue"; 
import Vuex from "vuex";
import createPersistedState from "vuex-persistedstate"

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    strict: true, 
    plugins: [
        createPersistedState()
    ],
    state: {
        token: null, 
        user: null, 
        isUserLoggedIn: false, 
    },
    getters: {
        isLoggedIn(state) {
            return state.isUserLoggedIn;
        }
    },
    
    mutations: {
        setToken(state, token) {
            state.token = token;
            if (token) {
                state.isUserLoggedIn = true;
            } else {
                state.isUserLoggedIn = false;
            }
        },
        setUser(state, user) {
            state.user = user; 
        }
    },
    actions: {
        setToken ({commit}, token) {
            commit("setToken", token);
        },
        setUser ({commit}, user) {
            commit("setUser", user);
        }
    }
})
```

Login Component:

```js
<template>
  <div class="hero is-large">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="hero-body">
            
              <div class="field">
                  <div class="notification is-warning" v-show="error">{{error}}</div>
              </div>

              <h1 class="title">Login</h1>


              <div class="field">
                  <label for="username" class="name">Username</label>
                  <input type="text" class="input" name="username" v-model="username">
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                  <label for="username" class="name">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="input" name="password" v-model="password">
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                  <button class="button is-link"
                          @click="login"
                          v-bind:class="{'is-loading': pending}">Login</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import AuthenticationService from "../Services/AuthenticationService";

export default {
  name: "Login", 

  data () {
      return {
          username: "",
          password: "", 
          error: null, 
          pending: false, 
      }
  }, 
  methods: {
      async login () {
          try {
            // SET LOADING SPINNER
            this.pending = true; 

            // API REQUEST
            const response = await AuthenticationService.login({
                username: this.username,
                password: this.password, 
            });

            console.log(response);

            // CLEAR FORM
            this.pending = false; 
            this.username = "";
            this.password = ""; 

            this.$store.dispatch("setToken", response.data.token);
            this.$store.dispatch("setUser", response.data.user);

            this.$router.push({
                name: "Landing"
            })
          } catch (error) {
              console.log(error);
          }
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Show the part where you do `this.$store.dispatch("setToken", <SOMETHING not null>);`

Comment: Okay - I've appended the code to the post 

"Login Component"

Comment: Is there maybe a problem on the mutation? you can check the state of the store in browser using a addon like [VueDevtools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vue-js-devtools/).

Comment: I downloaded the chrome tool, and did as suggested. The mutation is working fine, and the state is being updated correctly. For some reason the v-if and v-else blocks are not changing once the state has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found what is wrong.When the user logged in you did not set the isUserLoggedIn to true.So make an action and then a mutation to change to isUserLoggedIn to true when the user logged in successfully.

> Action

```
setUserLogged ({commit}) {
 commit("setUserLogged", true);
}
```

> Mutation

```
setUserLogged(state, payload) {
 state.isUserLoggedIn = true
}
```

Then in Login component in those lines change this:

```
this.$store.dispatch("setToken", response.data.token);
this.$store.dispatch("setUser", response.data.user);
```

to this:

```
this.$store.dispatch("setToken", response.data.token);
this.$store.dispatch("setUser", response.data.user);
this.$store.dispatch("setUserLogged");
```

Comment: forgive me if I'm wrong, but are you sure? I've set the isUserLoggedIn State to true in the setToken Mutation

<pre> <code> 
mutations: {
        setToken(state, token) {
            state.token = token;
            if (token) {
                state.isUserLoggedIn = true;
            } else {
                state.isUserLoggedIn = false;
            }
        },

</code> </pre>

Comment: Update - I tried what you suggested regardless. I did not work :(

Comment: I did the same in my project and works.The problem will be in login component.Try to remove async and all other stuff and only make a request to server for login.In callbar "then" put you dispatches

Comment: Actually before change the login method...in navbar component try set the "user" property to empty string ('') and in computed method get the user from vuex store.To do that create also another getter for returning the user

Comment: Hey I did that and it worked. I need to set a computed method to get the user from the store and that worked perfectly. Thank you so much. It was bugging me the whole day.

Comment: Glad to help you.Sometimes we stuck at something small.If that happened try to clean your mind and come back with cleam mind. :)